# Finding all subsets closed under multiplication

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{x\in\Bbb{R}~:~1\le|x|\le100\}$. I have to find all subsets $M$ of $S$ such that for all $x,y\in M$, their product $xy$ is also in $M$.

If the MiniMum magnitude among the elements of $M$ is $a$, then the maximum magnitude among the elements of $M$ is $100/a$. But after this I am getting confused. Please help.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696111/reposting-the-same-question-finding-all-subset-closed-under-multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** If $M$ has an element of modulus greater than 1 then it is unbounded.