# Reposting the same question (finding all subset closed under multiplication)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

> The question is same as the link [Finding all subsets closed under multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758325/finding-all-subsets-closed-under-multiplication)

And the answer,i didn't get it ...can you please elaborate more ...

Let's begin by noting that if 0 is in M, then M must consist only of $0$ because any non-zero number multiplied by $0$ is $0$, which is already in $M$. Therefore, let's assume that $0$ is not in $M$.

Now, let's consider the case where $M$ contains only positive or only negative numbers. In this case, any two numbers in $M$ will have a positive product, which means that $M$ cannot satisfy the given condition that $xy$ is in $M$ for all $x$, $y$ in $M$. Therefore, $M$ must contain both positive and negative numbers.

Let $A$ be the set of positive numbers in $M$ and $B$ be the set of negative numbers in $M$. Since $M$ does not contain $0$, we have $A ∩ B = ∅$.

Now, let's consider the product of any two numbers in $A$. If $xy$ is in $M$, then $xy$ must be positive, which means that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. Therefore, $A$ is closed under multiplication. Similarly, $B$ is also closed under multiplication.

Next, let's consider the product of a number in $A$ and a number in $B$. If $xy$ is in $M$, then $xy$ must be negative, which means that $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs. Therefore, $M$ contains all possible products of a positive number and a negative number.

Let's denote the maximum positive number in $M$ by a and the minimum negative number in $M$ by b. Since $1 ≤ |x| ≤ 100$ for all $x$ in $S$, we have $a ≤ 100$ and $|b| ≤ 100$. Therefore, the product $ab$ is in $M$.

If $ab$ is positive, then $a$ and $b$ are both positive or both negative, which means that $M$ contains all numbers between $a$ and $b$, including $a$ and $b$ themselves. On the other hand, if $ab$ is negative, then $M$ contains all numbers less than $b$ and all numbers greater than $a$, but not $a$ or $b$ themselves.

In summary, the subsets of $S$ that satisfy the given condition are of the form $M = {a, -a}$ or $M = {a, -a, b, -b, ab}$, where $1 ≤ a ≤ 100$ and $-100 ≤ b ≤ -1$.

Is this in correct way?

Comment: Not only is your answer wrong, but it sounds like you did not understand the problem correctly. For example, how is $M = \{a, -a\}$ closed under multiplication when $1 \le a \le 100\,$?

Comment: Oou yes .. mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

You've made quite a few mistakes in your post. Being more careful about some of these things will help a lot in improving your understanding the proof given.

First, it is not correct to say that "If zero is in $M$ then $M$ contains only zero". Notice that $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ is closed under multiplication because you have the following multiplication table:

$\begin{array}{c|ccc} \times & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline -1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}$

and every item in that table is an element of $M$.

Instead, I would say that if $0 \in M$, then $M$ is closed under multiplication if and only if $M \setminus \{0\}$ is closed under multiplication. Although this point is actually moot for this particular problem, since $0 \notin S$ to begin with.

Second, considering $A$ as the positive elements of $M$ and $B$ as the negative elements, it *is* true to say that $A$ is closed under multiplication, but $B$ is definitely *not* closed under multiplication (unless it is empty), because for any $x, y \in B$ you have $x < 0, y < 0$ but $xy > 0 \notin B$.

Third, probably the most important thing that you've missed is the actual key thing you need to prove. Notice that since all of the elements of $S$ are inside the interval $[-100, 100]$, the elements of $M$ are also bounded. But if $a \in M$, then $a^2, a^3, a^4, \ldots \in M$. If $|a| > 1$, then there must exist a positive integer $n$ such that $|a^n| > 100$ (proof left as an exercise). That means that $M$ can contain no elements with modulus greater than 1. Since the only elements of $S$ with modulus less than or equal to 1 are -1 and 1, the only possibilities for $M$ are:

1. $\{\}$
2. $\{1\}$
3. $\{-1\}$
4. $\{-1, 1\}$

and it's fairly straightforward to check each of them as to whether they're closed under multiplication (hint: one of them isn't).